# Power analysis for model comparison between linear mixed-effects models

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, statistical-power, model-comparison

I am trying to model the effect of 3 continuous predictors on a binary choice outcome. These data come from an experiment in which multiple subjects were ran in a task containing multiple trials (hence the random intercept of subject, and the random slopes for each predictor). Suppose I have these three nested linear mixed models (using `lme4` package in `R`):

```
model.1 <- glmer(choice ~ 1 + beta1 + beta2 + (1 + beta1 + beta2|subject),
                         data=data, family=binomial(link="probit"))

model.2 <- glmer(choice ~ 1 + beta1 + beta2 + criticalbeta + (1 + beta1 + beta2 + criticalbeta|subject),
                         data=data, family=binomial(link="probit"))

model.3 <- glmer(choice ~ 1 + (beta1 + beta2) * criticalbeta + (1 + beta1 + beta2 + criticalbeta|subject),
                         data=data, family=binomial(link="probit"))
```

What I am interested in answering is not so much whether `beta1`, `beta2`, and `criticalbeta` are significant, but whether the addition of the `criticalbeta` term as an additive or multiplicative parameter, better fits the data when modeling the outcome `choice`. Additionally, it could be that neither the additive model or multiplicative model fit the data better, in which case I would conclude that the addition of the `criticalbeta` was not necessary.

What I have been doing to compare these models, since the terms are nested, is running them through the `anova()` like so:

```
anova(model.1, model.2, model.3)
```

This gives me the output (similar to):

```
Data: data

Models:
model.1: choice ~ 1 + beta1 + beta2 + (1 + beta1 + beta2|subject)  
model.2: choice ~ 1 + beta1 + beta2 + criticalbeta + (1 + beta1 + beta2 + criticalbeta|subject)        
model.3: choice ~ 1 + (beta1 + beta2) * criticalbeta + (1 + beta1 + beta2 + criticalbeta|subject)

         Df   AIC   BIC  logLik deviance   Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
model.1  46 14516 14878 -7211.8    14424                              
model.2  67 14455 14983 -7160.7    14321 102.332     21  1.114e-12 ***
model.3  83 14467 15120 -7150.3    14301  20.744     16     0.1886    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

While I believe this is the easiest way to compare the model that best fits the data, I am a little stuck on how I would go about constructing a power analysis for this model comparison. I need to be able to justify that I can collect enough data (i.e. enough subjects, with enough trials) to have >95% power to detect an effect.

I have found resources online for how to conduct a power analysis for each model, but can anyone point me to resources on (or explain, possibly) how one would go about setting up a power analysis for a model comparison?